# How is $u(at+b) = u(t+b/a)$ for $a>0$ and $u(-t-b/a)$ for $a<0$?

Tags: continuous-signals

I've come across this equality that I don't know how to prove. I've tried using the delta function due to its relationship to the step function, but I can't reach any results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- General definition of the unit-step function: $$u(t-t_0) = 
     \begin{cases} 1 &t>t_0\\ 0 &t<t_0 \end{cases} $$
- Let's write it for $u(at+b)$:  $$u(at+b) =  \begin{cases} 1 &at>-b \\
     0 &at<-b  \end{cases} \tag{1} $$
- Now recall from basic algebra that:

> $$at > -b \implies \begin{cases} t>-\frac{b}{a} & a > 0\\ 
>  t<-\frac{b}{a} & a < 0\\ \end{cases} $$ and similarly, that:    $$at <
>  -b \implies  \begin{cases} t<-\frac{b}{a} & a > 0\\    t>-\frac{b}{a} & a < 0\\  \end{cases} $$

---

So for $a>0$ we can write $(1)$ as:
$$u(at+b) =
\begin{cases}
1 &t>-\frac{b}{a} \\
0 &t<-\frac{b}{a} 
\end{cases}
\quad= u(t+b/a)
$$
and for $a < 0$ we can write $(1)$ as:
$$u(at+b) =
\begin{cases}
1 &t<-\frac{b}{a} \\
0 &t>-\frac{b}{a} 
\end{cases}
\quad= 1 - u(t+b/a) = u(-t-b/a)
$$

> the last step involves the time inversion property of the unit step
> function, which states: $$u(-t) = 1 - u(t)$$